# Can we configure ambari to non-root user in an existing cluster

Tags: hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I know to configure ambari for non root user while setting up a  fresh cluster, But is it possible to do this in a existing  cluster which is run by root.

Appriciate your help.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, to do so run the `ambari-server setup` command again.

```
Customize user account for ambari-server daemon?, choose y.
```

Also, remember to provide the non root user to have sudo access. Just like following the steps for the first time, you have to [configure the non root user](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.1.0/bk_ambari-security/content/how_to_configure_ambari_server_for_non-root.html) for proper privileges.

Reference:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/138060/is-there-any-way-to-change-ambari-server-user-afte.html